# Run Stored Procedure via OraOLEDB

Tags: excel, stored-procedures, oraoledb, vba

I have the following stored procedure that I have to call from VBA.

```
declare
    p_segment1 varchar(25);
    p_segment2 varchar(25);
    p_segment3 varchar(25);
    p_segment4 varchar(25);
    p_segment5 varchar(25);
    p_valid_flag varchar(1);
begin
    p_segment1 := 'code segment here';
    p_segment2 := 'code segment here';
    p_segment3 := 'code segment here';
    p_segment4 := 'code segment here';
    p_segment5 := 'code segment here';

    apps.key_validate_gl_code_comb(p_segment1, p_segment2, p_segment3, p_segment4, p_segment5, p_valid_flag);
    dbms_output.put_line('Flag: ' || p_valid_flag);
end;
```

I need to call this procedure in VBA from Excel, but I am getting an error message by running the following code:

```
    Set pCommand = New Command
    Set pProcedureRecordset = New Recordset
    With pCommand
        Set .ActiveConnection = pConnection
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        Set p_Segment1 = .CreateParameter("p_segment1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, 'code segment here')
        Set p_Segment2 = .CreateParameter("p_segment2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, 'code segment here')
        Set p_Segment3 = .CreateParameter("p_segment3", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, 'code segment here')
        Set p_Segment4 = .CreateParameter("p_segment4", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, 'code segment here')
        Set p_Segment5 = .CreateParameter("p_segment5", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, 'code segment here')
        Set p_Valid_Flag = .CreateParameter("p_valid_flag", adVarChar, adParamInputOutput, 1)
        .Parameters.Append p_Segment1
        .Parameters.Append p_Segment2
        .Parameters.Append p_Segment3
        .Parameters.Append p_Segment4
        .Parameters.Append p_Segment5
        .Parameters.Append p_Valid_Flag
        .CommandText = "apps.key_validate_gl_code_comb(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        Set pProcedureRecordset = .Execute
    End With
```

When I run this in SQL Developer, I get the desired output, but when I run it from VBA I get an `Unspecified Error` message.

How can I call a stored procedure from VBA to get an output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your connection is correct and you want to get only the output var as result, you don't need any Recordset variable (and if execute returns a recordset, it will create it for you).

I found some things to correct, after that I could successfully execute your code

- Even if `p_valid_flag`, you have to set a value.
- The proc is called without the `?`-placeholder.

Just an advice (not related to your actual problem): Declare you variables and use `Option Explicit`

```
 Set pCommand = New ADODB.Command
 With pCommand

    Set .ActiveConnection = pConnection
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    Set p_Segment1 = .CreateParameter("p_segment1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, "code segment here")
    ...
    Set p_Valid_Flag = .CreateParameter("p_valid_flag", adVarChar, adParamInputOutput, 1, "")

    .Parameters.Append p_Segment1
    ...
    .Parameters.Append p_Valid_Flag

    .CommandText = "apps.key_validate_gl_code_comb"
    .Execute
    Debug.Print "-->" & p_Valid_Flag.Value
End With
```

Comment: I always use Option Explicit Just posted the relevant code for the Oracle Function :)